# How do you find the shape of a tensor in tensorflow js?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow

I am trying to get the shape of a tensor in TensorFlow js but am unable to do so. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Did you try?:

```
tf.shape
```

Where tf is your tensor, you can read more about this function at the tensorflow [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/shape)